# add Lua files to C++ program

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Lua script that is run on a C++ compiled program (tg). My C++ program is [tdbot](https://github.com/vysheng/tdbot). The Lua script is written in Lua 5.2.  Is there any way that I can add my Lua files to this C++ program?

I want to implement this to protect my license codes.

Comment: Replace [this line](https://github.com/vysheng/tdbot/blob/a838e8768f1c405306975763d59d48ca9f347805/clilua.cpp#L168) by `int r = luaL_dostring (luaState_, "my script as a string here");`

Comment: “I want to implement this to protect my license codes.” Have you heard of reverse engineering?  That's almost trivial when you embed your script as a string into the executable.

Comment: Embedding Lua code in C++ code is trivial; just turn your data into an array of bytes. `xxd` does this for you and even generates a .h file. More importantly though, this is just as easy to deobfuscate, as this will effectively embed the Lua code as binary data right into your executable, so you can even open it in notepad and somewhere among the binary nonsense your Lua script will just be there as plain text.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "license codes".

Comment: @HenriMenke yes I heard about reverse engineering.the persons who I worked with them just can decompile easy source codes like lua..

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer in other word when user run my source the client request to my site and get data.I wanna save this codes that they can't change it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Do I put all my codes in that line? My source is about 1000 lines

Comment: @user11020732 You don't have to pass it as a literal string, you can also store it in a `const char *` which you then pass to `luaL_dostring`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using lua bytecode? Unlike embedding lua code, it is not so trivial to be reverse-engineered. Of course it is not 100% secure, but it is much harder than lua text code.

If you are not familiar with *bytecode*, it is a kind of assembly language for a virtual machine. Conceptually "C code" - "assembly code" relation is similar to "lua code" - "lua bytecode".

Let me show you how to do it.

Firstly compile your `a.lua` file to *lua bytecode*.

```
$ luac -o a.luac a.lua
```

And you now have `a.luac` which is lua bytecode. It is binary-format. You can use `luaL_loadfile` in the same way. It automatically detects whether it is text code or byte code. So for example:

```cpp
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"

int main() {
  lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  luaL_loadfile(L, "a.luac");
  lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

  lua_close(L);

  return 0;
}
```

If you really need to embed this code in your C code, you may consider `luaL_loadbuffer` which loads lua code/bytecode from memory rather than a file. Also need to pre-process embedding the bytecode.